# Make AWS Lambda send back a file after several minutes of processing

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, httprequest, aws-api-gateway

I have a node app that takes an url, scrape some text with puppeteer and translate it using deepl before sending me back the result in a txt file. It works as expected locally but having a lot of urls to visit and wanting to learn, I'm trying to make this app works with AWS Lambda and a docker image.

I was thinking about using a GET/POST request to send the url to API Gateway to trigger my lambda and wait for it to send me back the txt file. The issue is the whole process takes 2/3 minutes to complete and send back the file. It is not a problem locally but I know you should not have an http request wait for 3 minutes before returning.

I don't really know how to tackle this problem. Should I create a local server and make the lambda post a request to my ip adress once it is done?

I'm a loss here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can see a few alternatives to what is seemingly asynchronous processing concern.

Poke the lambda with the data it needs (via an API, SDK, or CLI) then have it write its results to an S3 bucket.  One could poll the s3 bucket for the results asynchronously and pull them down, obviously this requires some scripting.

An another approach would be to have the lambda post the results to a SNS topic that you've subscribed to.

That said, I'm not entirely sure what is meant by local IP, but I would avoid pushing data directly to a self-managed server (or your local IP), rather I would want to use one of the AWS "decoupling" services like SNS, SQS, or even S3 to split apart processing steps.  This way it's possible to make many requests and pull down the data as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I was about to make my lambda store the response in MongoDB Atlas to query it later but you're right, why leave the AWS environment.

Thanks, have a good day!